# Pyomo Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, pyomo

I am building an optimization model in pyomo and keep facing this error which I cannot solve.
Here is the part where the error occurs:

```
model.ct2demand = ConstraintList()
for n in model.N: 
    for s in model.S:
        for t in model.T: 
            for p in model.P:
                lhs = model.f[p,t,s,n]*1000 
                rhs = model.y[p,t,s,n] + model.sales[p,t,s,n] + model.error[p,t,s,n] 
                model.ct2demand.add (lhs == rhs)
```

the variable f and error are multidimensional parameters (non-negative reals), which I entered as numpy arrays and think are causing this issue based on my research, but I haven't really figured out exactly why. y and sales are decision variables. And the following is the error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21076/2031668078.py in <module>
    422             for p in model.P:
    423                 lhs = model.f[p,t,s,n]
--> 424                 rhs = model.y[p,t,s,n] + model.sales[p,t,s,n] + model.error[p,t,s,n]
    425                 model.ct2demand.add (lhs == rhs)
    426 

pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.NumericValue.__add__()

pyomo\core\expr\numeric_expr.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr._generate_sum_expression()

pyomo\core\expr\numeric_expr.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr.SumExpression.add()

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I did some research but still didn't really get what is causing the issue here.
Any guidance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It isn't real clear how you constructed `f` and `error`, but why don't you just make them Pyomo parameters and get numpy out of the model.  It will be a lot easier to troubleshoot and read.

Comment: Hi Airsqud! Thanks a lot for your comment. I constructed following a tutorial on youtube, so basically model.f = Param(model.P, model.T, model.S, model.N, initialize=f) after I input the data for f as a numpy array of 4 dimensions. Could you maybe explain what you mean by making them pyomo parameters? i thought I already declared them as pyomo parameters, but maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: you cannot use a numpy array to initialize the parameter if it is 4-dimensional.  You need to move the data (somehow...don't know what you started with) to a dictionary that is indexed like you want the param to be.

Comment: Do you have the data for these 2 items separately, and if so, in what format?  Or did you receive it in a numpy array (which would be odd).

Comment: Hi Airsquid, thanks a lot for your comment! I only used CPLEX before, so my understanding about python dictionary and use of numpy array is a bit limited. I have the data for the 2 items separately, and I literally just put them in a numpy array. so, before I initialized the parameters, I have put :   f = np.array ([data in 4 dimensions as in the index p,t,s,n with many more brackets]). Same for error parameter. Then after than I initialize the parameters as I told you, model.f = Param(model.P, model.T, model.S, model.N, initialize = f). Thanks a lot for your help, by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what is going on.  When you are initializing your parameter, you are failing to pass in a key:value pairing (like a dictionary) so `pyomo` is just initializing **each** element in your parameter to the *whole array* which is clearly not what you want.

Most of the time, the indexing sets are not just counting numbers, so this doesn't really pop up too often, because if your index is {'A', 'B', 'C', ...} then it becomes clear that you *must* pass in a key:value mapping in order to straighten that out.

Here are a couple lines to demo what I'm talking about.  Bottom line:  get `numpy` out of your model and make a dictionary of the stuff you want to use in the parameter.  (This can also be done w/ `pandas`, but it isn't necessary).  List of commands at end if you wish to copy/replicate/experiment.

```
In [1]: import pyomo.environ as pyo

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: np_data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [4]: m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

In [5]: m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=range(2))

In [6]: m.T = pyo.Set(initialize=range(2))

In [7]: # let's make a parameter from the data...

In [8]: m.p = pyo.Param(m.S, m.T, initialize=np_data)
WARNING: DEPRECATED: The default domain for Param objects is 'Any'.  However,
    we will be changing that default to 'Reals' in the future.  If you really
    intend the domain of this Param (p) to be 'Any', you can suppress this
    warning by explicitly specifying 'within=Any' to the Param constructor.
    (deprecated in 5.6.9, will be removed in 6.0) (called from
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-
    packages/pyomo/core/base/indexed_component.py:665)

In [9]: # note we get this odd warning about an "any" type.  This is trigge
   ...: red by fact that we are initializing EACH item to the whole array

In [10]: m.p[0,1]
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [11]: m.p[1,1]
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [12]: # not good!  pyomo wants a key:value pair

In [13]: my_better_data = {(0, 0) : 1,
    ...:                   (0, 1) : 2,
    ...:                   (1, 0) : 3,
    ...:                   (1, 1) : 4}

In [14]: m.p2 = pyo.Param(m.S, m.T, initialize=my_better_data)

In [15]: m.p2[0,1]
Out[15]: 2

In [16]: %hist
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
np_data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=range(2))
m.T = pyo.Set(initialize=range(2))
# let's make a parameter from the data...
m.p = pyo.Param(m.S, m.T, initialize=np_data)
# note we get this odd warning about an "any" type.  This is triggered by fact that we are initializing EACH item to the whole array
m.p[0,1]
m.p[1,1]
# not good!  pyomo wants a key:value pair
my_better_data = {(0, 0) : 1,
                  (0, 1) : 2,
                  (1, 0) : 3,
                  (1, 1) : 4}
m.p2 = pyo.Param(m.S, m.T, initialize=my_better_data)
m.p2[0,1]
%hist

In [17]:
```

#### Edit to show conversion of multi-dim np array to dict

You can convert the `np.array` back to a dictionary only in the special case where the indices all line up to equivalent sets very easily.  **just double check** that the indexing is happening as you like by sampling a few values or printing out the parameter completely with `model.p.pprint()`

```
In [30]: data = list(range(12)) # some fake data

In [31]: data_np = np.array(data)

In [32]: data_np = data_np.reshape(3,2,2)

In [33]: data_np
Out[33]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])

In [34]: data_dict = dict(np.ndenumerate(data_np))

In [35]: data_dict
Out[35]: 
{(0, 0, 0): 0,
 (0, 0, 1): 1,
 (0, 1, 0): 2,
 (0, 1, 1): 3,
 (1, 0, 0): 4,
 (1, 0, 1): 5,
 (1, 1, 0): 6,
 (1, 1, 1): 7,
 (2, 0, 0): 8,
 (2, 0, 1): 9,
 (2, 1, 0): 10,
 (2, 1, 1): 11}

In [36]:
```

Comment: Hi AirSquid, thanks a lot for your comment. I now get what is wrong. It's a shame that I cannot directly put my data like that, I thought it was really convenient,haha But thank you! I guess I will have to put all the data in a huge list. Thanks again for your detailed answer

Comment: well, if the indices within the numpy array directly align with your sets (which would be a bit odd, as mentioned), you could us `np.ndenumerate` to enumerate out the array into a dictionary.  Honestly, with dictionary comprehensions, it is usually a snap to ingest data in any format

Comment: Thanks alot for the tip! Yes, the numpy array aligns with my set, so the most our bracket corresponds to n, then s, then t and then p. I just expected np array to work how it is in CPLEX, haha. So the most inner bracket corresponds to a set of product (p1 to p8) and then then the outer one corresponds to a set of time in weeks (from 1 to 52) etc. I did some research meanwhile and found that 'tolist' does something similar, it turns a numpy array into a list. But I will try np.ndenumerate first!

Comment: added an example of the back-conversion

Comment: Thank you so much!! I enumerated everything in list and my model is up and running. Thanks a ton!!